# A Grammar And some challenge about SLR, LALR

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, ll-grammar, lalr, lr-grammar

I know:

> > A language is said to be LL(1) if it can be generated by a LL(1) grammar. It can be shown that LL(1) grammars are

```
not ambiguous and
not left-recursive.
```

but i ran into a problem.

Why the Grammar

> > S-> aBDb
> >
> > B -> lambda
> >
> > D-> dD | lambda

why this grammar is not LL(1) nor SLR nor LALR? anyone could describe me?

Comment: no need to worry - that grammar is LL(1) and SLR(1). Who told you that is not?

Comment: Dear @Gunther, this is a Test on P.hd Entrance exam. the answer key says this is not.

Comment: Another user suggests that this question has a typo in it that makes the grammar LL(1), SLR(1), and LALR(1). With the typo removed, the grammar is not LL(1), SLR(1), or LALR(1). However, I think it's probably best if that's posted as a different question, since otherwise I have to completely redo my answer from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grammar is indeed LL(1). Here's the parse table:

```
      a     b     d       $
S     aBDb
B           eps   eps
D           eps   dD
```

It's also SLR(1). Here are the FOLLOW sets:

```
S: $
B: d, b
D: b
```

Here are the configurating sets:

```
 S' -> .S$ 
 S  -> .aBDb  ($)

 S' -> S.$

 S  -> a.BDb   ($)
 B  -> .       (b, d)

 S  -> aB.Db   ($)
 D  -> .       (b)
 D  -> .dD     (b)

 D  -> d.D     (b)
 D  -> .dD     (b)
 D  -> .       (b)

 D  -> dD.     (b)
```

There are no shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts, so this grammar is SLR(1). Therefore, it's also LALR(1).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dear templatetypede, would you please send your email address?

Comment: your answer is completely wrong, it's not LALR and nor SLR.

Comment: @user153695 It's possible that I've made a mistake here, but I don't see what it is. Can you point out what error I've made? I'd like this answer to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @user153695 My apologies - I found my mistake. I left a production out of one of the SLR states. Answer updated!

Comment: i sure that this is not LL(1) nor SLR nor LALR, would u agree with me ?

Comment: is there any on-line tools to check this grammar is LL(1)?

Comment: @user153695 Wait a minute - you changed the grammar in the question a few hours ago, which invalidated my answer. That's not okay - how do you know for sure that there's a typo in the original grammar? Please post that as a separate question; I'm rolling this back to the question that I answered.

Comment: no, i see this question as an exam. this is exactly the same. from the comment by that user that it's not LR nor SLR nor LALR, we know there is a typo. please correct it. !

Comment: @user153695 That would entirely change the answer to the question and require me to go back and update what I have here. Instead, why don't you ask a follow-up question with the right grammar? That way, there will be answers both to the correct version of the question and to this interesting but incorrect version of the question. (Also, is it really ethical to post exam questions here?)

Comment: i'm sorry, after the change i post a comment, but i think edit it here. i'm sorry if i do something wrong.

Comment: Dear templatetypedef, i have another question on one another of your answer, can i ask?